# Fetch table headers in horizontal format | PLSQL |

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql, oracle-apex

I am bit stuck with it not getting where I am suppose to change and how to execute

I need to get specific table header in horizontal format with comma separated

**example :** `header1,header2,header3`

**Used a sample code and edited according to my need**

```
create or replace getdetails( vtable_name varchar2 , out voutput)
return varchar2
  as 
      v_sql varchar2(40000) :='';
BEGIN
      v_sql ='select listagg(column_name,',') within group (order by column_name) items from user_tab_columns where table_name :=vtable_name;'

EXCEPTION
    when no date_found then retrun '0';
    when others        then retrun '0';
END;
```

Need to get output into a variable

Comment: Your PL/SQL code does not compile. You need to write either FUNCTION or PROCEDURE after the word `replace` and before the word `getdetails`. Also you don't assign any value to the `vout` parameter.

Comment: @Abra : Can you share the code how to achieve it

Comment: Refer to the Oracle documentation, namely [Dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/dynamic-sql.html#GUID-7E2F596F-9CA3-4DC8-8333-0C117962DB73) which is chapter 8 in the _Database PL/SQL Language Reference_

Comment: Why are you using dynamic sql here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use select into :

```
create or replace function getdetails( vtable_name varchar2 , out voutput)
return varchar2
  as 
      v_columns varchar2(4000) :='';
BEGIN
      select listagg(column_name,',') within group (order by column_name) 
        into v_columns
        from user_tab_columns 
       where table_name = vtable_name;
      dbms_output.put_line (v_columns);
      return v_columns;

EXCEPTION
    when no_data_found then retrun '0';
    when others        then return '0';
END;
```

Comment: This code cannot compile, because after `exception` you should list exception names, which cannot be `no date_found` (with space). And there's no `no_date_found` exception. And as already mentioned in the comments, you have to specify object type: `function` or `procedure`

Comment: @astentx, I used the OP's message and updated only the part that was under question, thankyou for highlighting other errors, I have corrected them now.